# Pandas df.describe(), why is my count, mean,std, min showing as columns?

Tags: pandas, layout, rows, mean, describe

Hi im using Jupyter to run a dataframe, I first used Groupby function, then Describe. However, the layout seems strange:

How do I make the Count, Mean, Std, Min, etc show as Rows instead of columns? Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIUC you want [`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas-dataframe-t) Use it at last after applying `....describe().T`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your quesiton

Answer (score 0):

You can use de transpose method:

Example:

```
df.describe()

        col_1               col_2   
count   1650.               1650        
mean    6230.046061.        12219.373333    
std     12301.105083        17956.187102    
min     16.000000           7   
25%     774.750000          2873.250000 
50%     1764.500000         4830
75%     5267.250000         16235   
max     100755.00           78043.00
```

df.describe().T will output:

```
        count   mean    std      min      25%    50%        75%      max
col_1   1650.0  6230.   12301    16.00.   774.   1764.     5267.    100755.00
col_2   1650.0  12219   17956.   7.00     2873   4830      16235.   78043.00
```